Error with GWT trying to load inherited module that does not exist
I am doing an Ant compile-full on a Java app that uses GWT. It fails with the following;
[ERROR] Unable to find 'Gaming.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
I do not know where it could be getting "Gaming" from, other than the fact that my user folderpath in Windows is 'C:\Users\Apex Gaming PCs'. The KATS.gwt.xml looks like this;
<module rename-to='kats'>

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.precompress.Precompress' />
    <inherits name='kats.KATS-BO' />

    <!-- <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.gray.Gray' /> -->
    <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.blue.Blue' />
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' /> -->

    <entry-point class='kats.client.KATS' />

    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <!--set-property name="gxt.user.agent" value="ie8,ie9,gecko1_9" / -->
    
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.conversionMode" value="strict" />

    <generate-with class="kats.server.generator.CreateableWidgetFactoryGenerator">
        <when-type-assignable class="kats.client.reflection.CreateableWidgetFactory" />
    </generate-with>

</module>

The only question I found with this problem pointed to Run Configurations in Eclipse, specifically the Arguments of it, but I do not have any configs/arguments in Eclipse. Plus, that issue was looking for inherited module with the default com.google instead of the renamed. Mine is replacing it with something totally different. The word "Gaming" does not appear anywhere in the project.
I've looked through the whole project for any variable or reference to my user filepath and verified my classpath is correct, it's looking at the project first before anything else.

In your case, it would probably be in your ant build.xml - can you share the GWT-related parts of that? Odds are the Gaming module is referenced there. Also, can you add more of the log around that error?
